# Creating child classes with methods accepting parameters of different types in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a class, Pawn, which is the base class for all "characters" in the game with properties such as health, that can move and die or speak, etc. One class extending this is the "Boy" class. The "Boy" class is the player controlled character in this game.

In order to control character "states", state classes are created. These have methods such as onEnterState, onStateTick and onLeaveState. A state might be used to represent crouching, walking, jumping, and will be send messages such as "keyPressed" "<-" to handle or ignore as it choses.

My problem is that my base "state" class has methods as follows:

```
function onEnter ( pawn:Pawn ) :void;
function onLeave ( pawn:Pawn ) :void;       
function onGameTick ( pawn:Pawn ) :void;        
function onAnimEnd ( pawn:Pawn ) :void;
```

As you can see this is actually an interface, but I did try base classes first until it became apparent that ActionScript3 doesn't like abstract classes much.

So anyway, a class "BoyJumpState" would obviously need to extend/implement this class/interface to ensure that the public methods are there for interaction, however this is hindered by the fact that ActionScript will not allow me to extend with, say, this:

```
public override function onEnter ( boy:Boy) :void { trace("Hey"); }
```

This is rejected compile-time because it doesn't match the blueprint (i.e it doesn't accept a Pawn). However, I need it to accept a Boy because methods specific to that class need to be utilised in the method body!

I'm figuring my original interface is the problem, and that I should be specifying that the parameter should instead *extend* pawn and not actually need to be one, however I'm not seeing any way to implement this in ActionScript.

...or I could be completely on the wrong track, in which case advisement would be gratefully received!

I realise I could not have the inheritance going on, but the game I'm making is more of a practice in Object Orientated Programming as it's more large-scale than what I'm used to. However I've moved out of my comfort language (Java) and I'm really beyond myself as to what to do here.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having with not getting some sort of Abstract Class going for you? I'm puzzled, because whenever you apply a base Class to a library symbol, the base Class is acting as an Abstract Class and the generated Class for the library symbol is the specific implementation. That's just one example, but I use Abstract/Base classes all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override the overridden method's signature to match a covariant type. If you need a specific type in a subclass's method, you have to check/cast in the overridden method though.

Comment: What it sounds like you're saying is no overriding is needed, and that it will instead create an overloaded method? Doesn't that mean that the interface contract will not be successfully fulfilled then, because there will be no onEnter ( pawn:Pawn ) and only onEnter ( boy:Boy )? This would kind of defeat the purpose of the interface altogether.

Comment: Well, it depends. If Boy offers the complete contract, Pawn should just implement the contract in a different way. So a basic interface could satisfy the functionality. ActionScript has no Generics, and does not allow co- or contravariant method signature overridings, so basically it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Realised that I never selected a best for this question I asked a long time ago. How rude of me. Thanks for the answer, I ended up implementing as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement an interface in AS3, signatures must match exactly.

You could check types at runtime, like this:

```
public override function onEnter ( pawn:Pawn ) :void
{
    var boy:Boy = pawn as Boy;
    if(boy)
    {
        trace("Hey");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public override function onEnter ( pawn:Pawn ) :void
{
  if(pawn is Boy)
  {
    //do something else
  }
  else
  {
    //do the normal
    super.onEnter(pawn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would approach this problem by upcasting to the type I need in each concrete class, so as per your example:

```
public override function onEnter ( boy:Boy) :void { trace("Hey"); }
```

I would change this to:

```
public override function onEnter ( pawn:Pawn) :void 
{  
     // do something all pawns can do!
     pawn.move();

     // do something only a boy can do!
     Boy(pawn).doSomething();
}
```

I would definitely use a base class, yes its true that Actionscript 3 doesn't support abstract classes the same way as say Java does, but that doesn't stop you from creating a base class and overriding the methods, I would still type the base class to an interface anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an interface that is implemented by `Boy` and `Pawn`, lets say `IPlayer`.

```
public class Boy extends Sprite implements IPlayer
```

And

```
public class Pawn extends Sprite implements IPlayer
```

You create an interface named `IPlayer` that has all matching public functions and getters/setters.

```
package
{
   public interface IPlayer
   {
      function destroy():void;
      function get x():Number;
      function get y():Number;
   }
 }
```

Now, you can update your functions like this

```
function onEnter ( player:IPlayer ) :void;
function onLeave ( player:IPlayer ) :void;       
function onGameTick ( player:IPlayer ) :void;        
function onAnimEnd ( player:IPlayer ) :void;
```

If you extend the class you dont have problems with overrriding the parameters' type, since the type is a little abstracted into an interface which both classes extend.